# Redirect 404, 422, 500 Ruby On rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, http-status-code-404

I would be redirected to the homepage of only 500, 404, 422 error appears, do-it is possible to "catch" all errors and redirect to homepage?

I tried that but it works for the 404 error.

```
  match "*path" => redirect("/"), via: :get
```

Thanks you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your route file:

```
#routes.rb
get '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#raise_not_found'
```

In your application controller

```
#application_controller.rb
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found 
rescue_from Exception, with: :not_found
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :not_found

def raise_not_found
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new("No route matches #{params[:unmatched_route]}")
end

def not_found
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404", layout: false, status: :not_found }
    format.xml { head :not_found }
    format.any { head :not_found }
  end
end

def error
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/500", layout: false, status: :error }
    format.xml { head :not_found }
    format.any { head :not_found }
  end
end
```

You can find this a complete resource [here](https://gorails.com/forum/error-handling-in-ruby-4)

Comment: Yes but i would like to redirect to root_url

Comment: just change `render file` by `redirect_to `

Answer (score 2):

For production env:

In production.rb file, add:

`config.exceptions_app = routes`

In routes.rb file, add:
Add

`%w[404 422 500 503].each do |code|
      get code,
          to: 'exceptions#show',
          code: code
    end`

Create `exceptions_controller.rb` file, add:

```
class ExceptionsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /exceptions/:code
  def show
    status_code = params[:code] || 500
    render status_code.to_s, status: status_code
  end
end
```

Create, 404.html.erb, 422.html.erb, 500.html.erb, 503.html.erb in directory: `views/exceptions`

Enjoy !